# How SUM array json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

How can I to sum elements of a JSON array like this, using jQuery:

```
{"formulagram":"470+6,7+33,5+236,2+4,5+0,3"}
```

and the result should be :

total : **751,2**

Nominal with comma and + is a sparator.

Thank you

Comment: What does the comma in `751,2` separate? You need to elaborate more on what is being summed.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst : total shown are not always round. but also coma and + serves merely as a separator nominal figures such as coma if nominal not with commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
var objForm = {
    formulagram:"470+6,7+33,5+236,2+4,5+0,3"
};

var str= objForm.formulagram;

str = str.split(',').join('.').split('+');

var total = 0;
$.each(str,function() {
    total += parseFloat(this);
});

total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

total = total.toString().replace('.',',');

console.log(total);
```

**I have created a demo below:**

```js
var objForm = {
  formulagram: "470+6,7+33,5+236,2+4,5+0,3"
};

var str = objForm.formulagram;

str = str.split(',').join('.');

$('#splitbyComma').html(str);

str = str.split('+');

var total = 0;
$.each(str, function() {
  total += parseFloat(this);
});

total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

total = total.toString().replace('.',',');

$('#result').html(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Replace Comma with dot (.)</p>
<p id="splitbyComma"></p>
<p><strong>Total:</strong>
</p>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the character ',' for '.' to represent floating numbers. Then you can use eval.

Code:

```
var str= "470+6.7+33.5+236.2+4.5+0.3";
var sum = parseFloat(eval(str));
```

You have to be careful because it can be risky to use eval. Read more in this thread [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Obligatory comment about security implications of `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more roundabout but automated way:

```
var formulaObject = JSON.parse({"formulagram":"470+6,7+33,5+236,2+4,5+0,3"})
var formulaString = formulaObject.formulagram
var formulaPoint = formulaString.replace(',', '.')
var formulaArray = formulaPoint.split('+')
var formulaSum = formulaArray.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + parseFloat(cur)
}, 0)
```